# How to determine current delimiter in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, delimiter

Is there a way to determine the current delimiter in MySQL?

The delimiter can be set like this: `DELIMITER //`

Or like this: `\d //`

But how do you get the current delimiter?

I tried browsing the results of `SHOW STATUS` and `SHOW VARIABLES` to no avail.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you just want to know which delimiter is set right now `\s` will show you that:

> Using delimiter:   //

Answer (score 2):

The delimiter is not a keyword or command on the server (it's not even a reserved keyword), so there is absolutely no way to get it back from the server (since the server doesn't know about it)

It's used by the **client** (and the client must support it), and only by the client.

If you try to send a `DELIMITER //` from a client that doesn't support it, you'll get a syntax error